# How to render form with initial errors?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I would like to know if there is a way to render form with initial errors using react-final-form?

Errors are backend only, so the front-end can not validate the field.

My first thought would be to render the the form and immediately submit it to display the errors.

Comment: For information, material design recommends to only show errors after user interaction. [ref](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors)

Comment: I guess, you are right, I will have to change my flow

Comment: what if you ignore `meta.touched` when you render the inputs -- it would display errors if you consider empty fields as invalid.

Comment: yeah it would, but then you lost the client error, cause the form remain editable